# Create flat CSV from XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to convert the data from an XML to a flat CSV using XSLD.
Does anyone know a function with which I can get the data flat?

**data**

```
<objects>
    <object>
        <name>A</name>
        <sku>SKU-A</sku>
        <variants>
            <variant>
                <sku>V-SKU-A1</sku>
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <sku>V-SKU-A2</sku>
            </variant>
        </variants>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>B</name>
        <sku>SKU-B</sku>
        <variants>
            <variant>
                <sku>V-SKU-B1</sku>
            </variant>
            <variant>
                <sku>V-SKU-B2</sku>
            </variant>
        </variants>
    </object>
</objects>
```

**desired result**

```
Name;SKU;Variant-SKU
A;SKU-A;V-SKU-A1
A;SKU-A;V-SKU-A2
B;SKU-B;V-SKU-B1
B;SKU-B;V-SKU-B2
```

**my current attempt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files>
    <file filename="example.csv" search="|" replace=" " quotes="double">
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
            <xsl:output method="text" />

            <xsl:variable name="qs" select="'&#34;'" />
            <xsl:variable name="qe" select="'&#34;;'" />
            <xsl:variable name="qeo" select="';'" />
            <xsl:variable name="qend" select="'&#34;&#xA;'" />

            <xsl:template match="object">

                <xsl:value-of select="$qs" /><xsl:value-of select="name" /><xsl:value-of select="$qe" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$qs" /><xsl:value-of select="sku" /><xsl:value-of select="$qe" />

                <xsl:apply-templates select="variants/variant" />

            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="variant">
                <xsl:value-of select="$qs" /><xsl:value-of select="sku" /><xsl:value-of select="$qe" />
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:text>Name;SKU;Variant-SKU</xsl:text> <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="objects/object" />
            </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
    </file>
</files>
```

**my current result**

```
Name;SKU;Variant-SKU
A;SKU-A;V-SKU-A1;V-SKU-A2
B;SKU-B;V-SKU-B1;V-SKU-B2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/objects">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>Name;SKU;Variant-SKU&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="object">
        <xsl:variable name="object-data">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="sku"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="variants/variant">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$object-data"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="sku"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This avoids repeated lookup of parent object's data by storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways this could be done, this is one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Name;SKU;Variant-SKU</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="objects/object/variants/variant"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="variant">
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::object/name"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::object/sku"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="sku"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniU7